# Dynamic divs on multiple lines appended to the right

Tags: html, css

I have a problem doing something but it's difficult to explain it.

I have a dynamic list of divs - 3,5 or 10 for example. Every div should be next to the other on one line. That's easy of course, but here is the problem. All divs are in a parent div with width: 200px for example. All 5 child divs have width of 30, 100, 50, 200 and 40 pixels for example. So all divs can't be on one line, some of them should move on the next line or maybe on a third line. That's also works at the moment.
My problem is that I want divs on every line to be appended to the right of the parent div.

Here is an example:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">Test</div>
    <div class="child">ok</div>
    <div class="child">Very very long text</div>
    <div class="child">Long text</div>
    <div class="child">adsdas</div
</div>

.parent {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
}
.child {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xy2goa3e/

I want Test, ok and Very very long text to be appended to the right.
Also Long text and adsdas to be appended to the right and everything should be dynamic.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need all dive in vertical line or horizontal?

Comment: In vertical like: http://jsfiddle.net/xy2goa3e/2/?

Comment: All 3 boxes on the first line should have float: right for example. That is the correct structure. The problem is that with float: right, the order of the divs is wrong

Comment: I think we need to see what this is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following css solved your issue:

```
.parent {
    width: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #ccc;
    text-align:right;
}
.child {
    display: inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Use `display: inline-block;` of child and Give `text-align:right;` to parent.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xy2goa3e/4/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add

```
.parent {
      display:inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xy2goa3e/6/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the `float` of your `.child` class from `left` to `right` seems to fix the issue - unless I misunderstand something?

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xy2goa3e/3/

Comment: Yes, this is the correct structure but the order of the elements is wrong. They should be reversed.

Comment: Allright, I didn't see your comment above until after then answer. I don't readily have any suggestions, then.